# Cannot ping Windows 7 machine by hostname

Tags: networking, windows-7

I have a home network of a few computers, one of which is an iMac running Mac OS and another is a PC running Windows 7. The PC is able to ping the iMac both by IP and hostname, but the iMac can only ping the PC by IP. I'd like it to be able to ping the PC by hostname as well.

Comment: How would you like the iMac to determine the PC's IP address from its hostname? (Most likely, the answer is to install Bonjour on the PC.)

Comment: I currently have Bonjour running, but I'm still unable to ping my machine from the Mac by hostname.

Answer (score 0):

first check your internet connection type in windows 7 not Set to **public** , if so change it to **home** or **work**.
in other-hand if you are using **static** IP address in your network  check DNS setting on MAC client.
and finally check your **windows firewall** settings.

Comment: My network is set to Home, and I'm not using a static IP. I've opened a hole in my firewall to accept HTTP connections from private networks. Should I have a static IP? If so, how do I determine what IP addresses to use for the DNS server?